# Why does my reputation drop by a few points every Friday night?

Tags: support, reputation, rules

For several weeks I have lost reputation points on the night between Friday and Saturday without explanation.

Two weeks ago I lost 2 points, last week I lost 4 points and last night I lost 4 points.

The problem is not losing points, but is not knowing why.

- Is an edit that has been deleted?
- Is there a bug?
- There is a rule that I do not know?
- Someone has a grudge against me?
- Is there a curse of on Friday night?

An idea of ​​future suggestion (if it is not a bug) is to show why I lost these points.

The question may have already been asked, but I have not found them.

Comment: do you happen to post one or two bad question that I manage to see each friday night?

Comment: Did you check the "show removed posts" checkbox at the bottom of your reputation page in your profile?

Comment: Don't be silly. There is no such thing as a curse.

Comment: What transformed you into a Unicorn then, @BoltClock?

Comment: @Mat: Magic. Which is definitely *not* the same thing as a curse.

Comment: That's what the wizards want you to believe, @BoltClock. Don't fall in their trap.

Comment: Thank you to you. It was the checkbox `"show removed posts"` that I had not checked. shame on me. :) And of course, the "curse" was a joke. :D

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As far as I can tell you are losing some score as questions with low views, score and no answer get automatically deleted by a batch job.

You seem to have edited a number of them, which of course gave you +2 rep. As the questions get deleted so goes the rep bonus.

Unfortunately, you can't see the questions because they are deleted and you need more reputation.

Comment: But if 'show removed posts' is checked, the OP would still see entries in their reputation history.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I did not know the existence of this batch job (although I suspected seeing the periodicity). And I have not checked the checkbox "`show removed post`"

Comment: That checkbox only applies to your own posts, @doy. You won't see other people's posts that you edited.

Comment: @Arjan: Thanks for this precision.